# Is there a bug in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

When I hit command option + in Pycharm I do not get the expected result. Could someone check if they too have this problem or is it just my computer.  When you hit command option + (Mac jargon) the expand recursively feature is suppose to activate but in my computer this increases the font.  I made a video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8HSkoeNZOs&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1):

Some special keys on a Mac Laptop override other keys.  So the command option + key on a Mac was triggering a Macintosh operation rather than a Pycharm operation. Simply go into the preferences where it says shortcuts -> accessibility -> zoom, and you can there turn it off, at least in Mac OS Sierra.